# (Angular 2/4/5/6) ngx-international-phone-number does not display correct flag

Tags: angular, npm, angular6

I'm using ngx-international-phone-number. Upon manually keying the numbers (e.g. country code for Aaland Islands), the wrong flag is shown.

[image: Dropdown Picture 1]

Also, double dropdowns are shown for Australia and Azerbaijian. 
[image: Dropdown Picture 2]

I've raised the issue in the npm library itself, but I believe it would take awhile - and therefore brought the issue here. Hopefully someone could help enlighten me on how to go about fixing it. Appreciate your help! I've searched through both the libraries for google-libphonenum and ngx-international-phone-number, but couldn't find what is causing it.

Here are the links for the library:

https://github.com/nikhiln/ngx-international-phone-number
https://github.com/ruimarinho/google-libphonenumber

Comment: Well this is an issue with the lib, but I can explain the Åland Island and wrong flag though. You see, Åland is part of Finland, so they have the same prefix (+358) Therefore the issue is why the Finnish flag is showing due to some bug since the prefix is the same. But as said, this is a problem with the lib and they need to fix it on their end...

Comment: oh I see, thanks for clarifying the issue! I think the double dropdowns is the only issue then.